# Hook for HMR with Vue & webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

Is there any option to set up hook when some of Vue component were updated with hot module replacement?

```
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

And now I would like to call some method.

Answer (score 1):

Searching through webpack HMR I have found two methods: [`dispose`](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#dispose-or-adddisposehandler) and [`removeDisposeHandler`](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#removedisposehandler).

### dispose

> Add a handler which is executed when the current module code is
>   replaced. This should be used to remove any persistent resource you
>   have claimed or created. If you want to transfer state to the updated
>   module, add it to the given `data parameter`. This object will be
>   available at `module.hot.data after` the update.

### removeDisposeHandler

Remove the handler added via dispose or `addDisposeHandler`.

So I added `dispose` in `created` hook and removed it in `destroyed` hook like this:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    callback(data) {
      console.log(data)
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.dispose(this.callback)
    } 
  },
  destroyed() {
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.removeDisposeHandler(this.callback)
    }
  },
}
```

I have tested it in my Vue CLI app and everything works perfectly: it invokes when exactly this module is changed, but does not when another.

Answer (score 1):

@Javas, thanks for hint. Solution that I'm looking for is:

```
module.hot.addStatusHandler(status => {
    console.log('module hot status', status)
});
```

I placed it into my entry file and it's called each time if any of components are hot-reloaded.